# encypt using php AES-256-CBC & decrypt unix commande line

Tags: php, aes

i have code in php for encypt using php AES-256-CBC

and i want to help to get decypt using unix commande line

this is my code in php line

```
$dataToEncrypt = hex2bin("6C38AD4E822835753F0E64928CB62744D73F878E763B227CFE8F445028527ACFE5DD0CD0352B396EDC8402414FC68DD5");
$aesKey = hex2bin("152bd89657e03fdc7375a00e1fb1a38bab097c103b803846");
$iv = hex2bin("B109DAE1B71B638E");
$result2 = openssl_encrypt($dataToEncrypt, 'AES-256-CBC', $aesKey, 3,$iv);
echo bin2hex($result2);
```

outputs is encypted by php

```
b2cf19a92ef12bc4ae2d78d73ab587e2178f23913aa132dbd7972d42387687a2c9eab89250dd7eba5709aaef1e8d417d
```

and for derypt it i want to use like this

```
openssl aes-256-cbc -d -K 152bd89657e03fdc7375a00e1fb1a38bab097c103b803846 -iv B109DAE1B71B638E -in encrypted.txt -out decrypted.txt
```

problem i can't get same result for decypt

Answer (score 0):

- Assuming that the encrypted data are stored in the *binary format* (and not as hex string) in the file `encrypted.txt`, which is e.g. possible with, [[1]](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.file-put-contents.php):

  ```
  file_put_contents('<path to encrypted.txt>', $result2);
  ```

  or with a hex-editor, the OpenSSL-statement for decryption is, [[2]](https://www.openssl.org/docs/man1.1.1/man1/openssl-enc.html):

  ```
  openssl aes-256-cbc -d -K 152bd89657e03fdc7375a00e1fb1a38bab097c103b8038460000000000000000 -iv B109DAE1B71B638E0000000000000000 -nopad -in encrypted.txt -out decrypted.txt
  ```

  The data are stored in the binary format in `decrypted.txt` by the OpenSSL-statement and can be read and displayed e.g. with, [[3]](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.file-get-contents.php):

  ```
  $decrypted = bin2hex(file_get_contents('<path to decrypted.txt>');
  ```

  or with a hex-editor.
- In the `openssl_encrypt`-call, the value `3` is used as the 4th parameter (`$options`), which corresponds to the flag-combination `OPENSSL_RAW_DATA | OPENSSL_ZERO_PADDING`. This means that the encrypted data are returned in the binary format and that no padding is used. This is possible because the plaintext has a length of 48 = 3 * 16 bytes and thus corresponds to an integer multiple of the blocksize (16 bytes). Due to the missing padding, the `-nopad` option must be used in the OpenSSL-statement. *Note:* Instead of the value `3` it's better to use `OPENSSL_RAW_DATA | OPENSSL_ZERO_PADDING`.
- The key has a length of 24 bytes and is therefore 8 bytes too short for [AES](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Advanced_Encryption_Standard)-256, which uses a 32-byte-key. The IV has a length of 8 bytes and is therefore also 8 bytes too short for AES, which uses an IV of 16 bytes (corresponding to the AES blocksize). `openssl_encrypt` and OpenSSL padd the key and the IV with `0`-values to the required length so that the values from the PHP-code or the padded values can be used in the OpenSSL-statement. *Note:* The use of a key and IV that are too short generally reduces the security and should be avoided.